# Elm debugger sidebar is too small. How to extend it?

Tags: elm

I have long Msg and they are the same except the last part. As you can see below - i can't tell the difference: - they are actually different.

[image]

I've open up the debugger with chrome and i saw this:
[image]

But this doesn't work on page reload as you might expect. It reverts back to 30 ch.

**Question:**

Where are this styles kept? So that by modifying them i always have this debugger-sidebar at 70 ch.
Or is there a better way to do this?

Node: It would be even better if i can make it resizable instead of fixed at 70 ch. But this is enough for now.

Answer (score 6):

You are not alone, there is a Github [issue](https://github.com/elm-lang/virtual-dom/issues/49) for this.

Answer (score 6):

As @Simon H pointed out this is not fixed yet . But until then - to have a resizable `debugger-sidebar` you can do this:

**Go into:**

`elm-stuff/packages/elm-lang/VirtualDom/Debug.elm`

Do a search for the class: `.debugger-sidebar`
and then add:

```
.debugger-sidebar {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 30ch;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(61, 61, 61);

  /* add this 2 lines */
  overflow-x: auto;
  resize: horizontal;
}
```

It works on save with elm-live also. But if you delete the elm-stuff folder for some reason it will get back to normal - because elm-stuff is build on the fly.
I've taken this from @rtfeldman pull-request [here](https://github.com/elm-lang/virtual-dom/pull/46/commits)

Hope that helps:)

**EDIT:**

There has been some improvements recently (model stays open during updates.. awesome !!:D ) and stuff was moved around. If you want this:
[image]

My gif recorder only does 600px - can't record the hole thing. To change the styles:

**step 1. go to:**

`elm-stuff/packages/elm-lang/virtual-dom/ < your version number ex 2.0.4 > /src/VirtualDom/Debug.elm` - and open up `Debug.elm`

**step 2.**
Find `styles` function, and inside, locate:

```
#debugger {
  width: 100%
  height: 100%;
  font-family: monospace;

  display: flex; -- add display flex here.
}
```

**step 3. find:**

```
.debugger-sidebar {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 30ch;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(61, 61, 61);

  width: 30%;  -- add this 3 lines - maybe you want more width then 30%.
  overflow-x: auto;
  resize: horizontal;
}
```

Don't delete `elm-stuff` folder - if you do all this steps need to be done again.

**For webpack users.**
And also make sure you restart webpack build after doing this - because webpack-dev-server is working form the unchanged elm-stuff folder in memory - and will not pick up this change without a restart.

Comment: Wow, I can resize it now. Thanks

Comment: Tried this but resizing ends up pushing the model info down below the sidebar.

Comment: @Bezewy that is true, there is another property that needs changing - the `width of the right container` - is set to `100% - 30ch`, the 30ch being the size of the `debugger-sidebar` - so just change that property to be `100% - 50ch` or something. I can't remember of the top of my head what is the name of the class, but you can find it immediately above the `.debugger-sidebar` as far as i can remember.