# elm-debugger window is closed with each page refresh. How to prevent that form happening?

Tags: elm

I find myself spending lots of time moving and resizing the elm-debugger window after each page refresh of the elm-live.

The ideal behavior will be the same as ChromeDeveloperConsole. When you have the **Developer Console** open, and you do a page refresh - the console is refreshed also.

The Chrome Developer window **stays in the place you put it** during the page refresh.

This is especially true when you have multiple monitors with multiple pages opened and resized carefully in specific places...

But if that is not possible right now, i tied at least to save myself time by avoiding resizing and moving this window.. This is what happens right now - by default:
[image]

Every time it has `900 x 360` and `its beneath the start bar`.

If the elm-debugger keeps the dimensions i want and the position i want - that's good enough for now..

**Update:**
I found the place where the parameters for the elm-debugger window are set: `VirtualDom.js` at line `1697`

```
function openDebugWindow(moduleName, popoutRef, virtualNode, eventNode)
{
    var w = 900;
    var h = 360;
    var x = screen.width - w;
    var y = screen.height - h;
    var debugWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=' + w + ',height=' + h + ',left=' + x + ',top=' + y);

    // switch to window document
    localDoc = debugWindow.document;
    ...
```

I've tryed changing the width and height but for some reason it doesn't work. Is like i didn't make any changes. This is odd - because i already seen the `elm-stuff` folder beeing reused with each page refresh - check the question here: [How to resize Msg pannel in elm-debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41555736/elm-debugger-sidebar-is-too-small-how-to-extend-it/41572246#41572246):

But why changes to Debug.elm are applied and this changes don't?

If i can fix any of this issues the experience of using elm-debugger will be improved a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a partial solution:

```
function openDebugWindow(moduleName, popoutRef, virtualNode, eventNode)
{
   var w = 900; -- i like this.
   var h = 560; -- i've changed the height.
   var x = screen.width - w ;
   var y = screen.height - h - 100; -- this change ensures that debugger window it's above the start.
   var debugWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=' + w + ',height=' + h + ',left=' + x + ',top=' + y);
```

I had the server still running when i've done thouse changes. You need to stop and restart the server for the .js files to be reloaded. Or else only the .elm files are watched. This is why changes to `Debug.elm` worked but the ones in `VirtualDom.js` didn't.

Check it out!
[image]

This is still not as nice as Chrome Developer Console but you only have to do 1 click - instead of resizing and moving the hole window on each page refresh ..

You don't need to remake this changes as long as you don't delete the `elm-stuff` folder. Enjoy! :)